# actionscript loader disapear when resizing it

Tags: image, flash, actionscript, resize, loader

So I am trying to resize a loader containing an image. and this is what happen : [image]

img_width being an int that I receive as a parameter. Note that when I am not trying to set the width or the height the image appear on the screen but now it is not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was a begginer mistake by me, I just had to make sure that the content was loader with a listener before resizing it.